# Android viruses are infecting my phone

Tags: virus

My phone has been infected with viruses for 6months now.

At first it was just a virus in disguise called "settings", but then it spread to my browsers opening many different sites. I had to disable my browsers. And now there are 3 other viruses on my phone. One called *"clockwallpaper"*, second is the *"lake worth isd"*. It creates a fake duplicate of an app that I'm using, and after I closed that duplicated app, the original app starts lagging and then crashes. It also activates the silent mode of my phone. The third one is called *"system"*, which pop-up tons of ads that is really annoying. It also makes an app that I'm using to lag and stop working.

I tried to use Malware Bytes and Bitdefender antivirus softwares. At first it was good and they removed the viruses, and I thought the viruses will be gone permanently. But I was wrong, after an hour or less they get installed again, even I have an internet connection or not.

So I performed a factory reset on my phone to get rid of it.

And they were gone. But then later on they get installed again and my phone was now like before.

Please help me!

Comment: The malware apps have gaoined root access and modified your system rom. The best way would be to re-flash a full factory ROM image.

Comment: @Robert makes a really good point, with root access, the best thing really would be to reflash a factory. Theres a decent guide here that covers steps to take with an infected phone [techadvisor](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/remove-android-virus-3633110/) and XDA developers provides a good resource for hot to reflash a factory rom [xda developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**Before using any steps backup your personal data**
Use a Bloatware free Stock-Rom or Custom rom which has support of your Android Phone. You can find your phone's stock rom on XDA-Developers forum.
Now comes the flashing step.

You can do it in two ways:-

**1.** Flashing from androd Recovery Mode in TWRP. **Requires root**
See Here to know how you can do it:-
https://www.google.com/search?q=flashing+roms+with+twrp

**2.** Flashing rom from PC. **This doesn't requires root.**
See here to know how to do it:-
https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+custom+rom+on+android+using+pc

These steps will remove the virus apps which were in your root and will give your phone a relief.